# How can I write a hook that gets called when a RubyGem is installed?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'd like to write a Ruby snippet that gets run when my Gem is first installed via `[sudo ]gem install mygem`.  Can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like it's really supported. I found a "post_install_message" attribute that you should be able to set in the gem spec, but that won't execute code.

You may be able to do it by packaging your on-install code as an extension in your gem (as if it were a native extension), and providing a Rakefile to "build" the extension (i.e. call your code).

Comment: I tried using post_install_message and it really won't run any code. I created a method executing my tasks and returning a string to satisfy the gemspec, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The best solution that I found is as follows:

```
# your_gem.gemspec
Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  # ...
  spec.extensions = ['Rakefile']
end
```

-

```
# Rakefile
task :prepare do
  # Execute your post-installation code here
end

task default: :prepare
```

Comment: Where did you put your Rakefile?  Were any other files e.g. extconf.rb?

Comment: You can put Rakefile into the same directory as your gemspec. extconf.rb is not needed.

Answer (score -3):

You can try to do this using call of OS commands. I'll quote eample from irb but you can do same in your scripts too.

```
irb(main):001:0> system 'gem list | grep rails'
rails (2.1.1, 2.1.0)
=> true
irb(main):002:0> system 'gem list | grep railssssss'
=> false
```

You can use result of this command as the condition of your snippet execution.