# How to use hooks in ruby gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a gem which needs some rake task to be executed after installation of the gem. There is a hackish way to execute a code after install using method described at http://blog.costan.us/2008/11/post-install-post-update-scripts-for.html.

However Gem class now has hooks, and one of them is a post_install hook. I am trying to add a line like

```
Gem.post_install { puts 'post hook example' }
```

into Rakefile and it does not seem to be executed during install. Where should this line to be placed for the hook to be registered?

Comment: check [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223151/how-can-i-write-a-hook-that-gets-called-when-a-rubygem-is-installed)

Comment: The OP already linked to that post...

Comment: also looking for this! any ideas?

Comment: @NikolaiTschacher now we [see why](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2016/06/infecting_syste.html)! Nice exposé of RubyGems vulnerability btw - my typing is much more careful as a result..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a file at `lib/rubygems_plugin.rb`

In this file you can define your custom hooks. For example:

```
Gem.post_install do
  puts "post_install called for gem"
end
```

No need to require anything.
Example output:

```
  Successfully built RubyGem
  Name: post_install_test
  Version: 0.1.0
  File: post_install_test-0.1.0.gem
post_install called for gem
Successfully installed post_install_test-0.1.0
1 gem installed
```

I only found the documentation for this in the [source](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/4a778c9c2489745e37bcc2d0a8f12c601a9c517f/lib/rubygems/installer.rb#L22).

If this doesn't work, or your changes to your post install hook don't always seem to update, uninstall the gem completely before rebuilding and installing it.