# How do I execute a ruby script when gem install is called?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-c-extension

I'm making a Ruby wrapper for a C Library that doesn't really have a system wide installation(the libxxx.a linkable library is distributed). During development, I was able to just keep this .a file in a local folder and refer to it using the C extension code. However this would be cumbersome for anyone who just wants to type gem install into their terminal. Since there is no system wide installation, I would need to execute an intermediate script that downloads the right distribution and then puts it in a generic folder within the gem directory itself.

To be clear, when someone types gem install, a tarball would get downloaded from an ftp, unpacked into the gem folder, and then gem install would proceed normally. If it helps, the C library in question is [CSPICE](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/toolkit_C.html)

Comment: While I don't consider this a good idea, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063725/how-to-use-hooks-in-ruby-gems should answer your question

Comment: @bjhaid : Thank you for pointing me in the direction of gem install hooks but I believe it is not possible to use it for a specific gem, it has to be enabled for a system wide RubyGems installation from what I've noticed.